# CORS issue - Or not?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, iis-express

I'm building a website in Angular 4.
My url server side (Web Api) was http://localhost:55499/api
My url  client side is http://localhost:4200.
And it worked well.
For various reasons I changed the url server to http://localhost/AAA/api/ and I start to use iis express instead local iis.
And since then it has stopped working.
Brings the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

The response had HTTP status code 400.

I have in my response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200`

I have in the controller:

`[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: " * ", methods: " * ")]`

I use IIS EXPRESS.

Comment: I would recommend not using `"*"` it's only working for the config. It should be like `Headers: POST, GET, OPTIONS` and same for methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the headers and methods you want to allow. You just have two empty strings for both.

Comment: ho, Im sorry, I dont know why but the "*"has been dropped.i have this line   [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the domain access issue you are on different domain trying to access the data or resource on different domain.

If you are using node_modules the install cors module. and use it in your **server app** as follows

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

or you can enable this for single a route as well as follows.

```
 var express = require('express')
    var cors = require('cors')
    var app = express()
    app.get('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
      res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
    })
```

And Also refer [stack answer by apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)